# I have an [allergy] to a tag [allergen]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have the following two tags:

- [allergy](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/allergy) (83 questions, tag wiki)
- [allergen](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/allergen) (15 questions, no tag wiki)

There is a scientific difference in meaning between these two words (an allergy is a medical condition while an allergen is a substance that triggers it), but I'm not finding this difference useful on this site for actually classifying questions. A brief review of the questions on both of these tags appears to show no rhyme or reason for one to be used or the other - rather, it seems to be random and up to the whims of the posters rather than any specific criteria. Quite a few questions have both tags, and I cannot find anything that distinguishes them from questions that have just one of the tags.

I propose that we keep the more popular tag [allergy](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/allergy) and make [allergen](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/allergen) a synonym.

Comment: I think I disagree. If you want to ask about particular allergens, then allergen would be a better tag to use in my mind than allergy.